# asp.net textbox adding BehaviorID

Tags: asp.net, javascript

can I add BehaviorID attribute for asp.net textbox and use it to be recognize by java script??

On other word, I want to to apply some java script function on asp.net text box and I want to let the java script find the asp.net text box by the  BehaviorID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TextBox.Attributes.Add will add the attributes correctly but they will not be XHTML compliant. In order to add XHTML compliant attributes you can use ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute method.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                BindData(); 
            }

        }

        private void BindData()
        {
           ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute("txtName","BehaviorID",String.Empty);
        }
```

The above will add the BehaviorID as a JavaScript property instead of adding attribute directly into the TextBox element.

Comment: @azamsharp: You aren't entirely correct about it not being XHTML compliant.  XHTML provides for a way to specify custom DTD for validation.  See examples here (http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customdtd/) and here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413147/are-custom-attributes-ok-in-xhtml).

Answer (score 1):

Sure. In your code-behind:

```
myTextBox.Attributes.Add("BehaviorID", id.ToString());
```

The resulting HTML will look something like:

```
<input type="text" BehaviorID="7" id="myTextBox" (...) />
```