# jQuery 'has attribute' selector fails in IE7 (for 'autofocus')

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to provide support for browsers which don't have support for the [autofocus](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control%3a-the-autofocus-attribute) attribute, using an approach something like this:

```
<input type="text" autofocus/>
<input type="text" autofocus="autofocus"/>
<input type="text"/>​

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[autofocus]").first().focus();
</script>
```

However, that selector is returning all input elements for IE7, including ones that don't have an 'autofocus' attribute. Its working for IE8+, and I have tested using jQuery 1.6.4, 1.7.2 and 1.8.2. I have a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HSC7K/4/.

These jQuery tickets seems related, but have been closed:

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5637

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7874

**Edit:**
updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HSC7K/6/

Comment: If you're using HTML5 you'll need to include one of the shiv's to allow elements like autofocus. Have you done that?

Comment: I'm using custom attributes, not HTML5 elements, so AFAIK it doesn't require a shiv. I've updated the fiddle to show that custom attributes are working, but if the attribute is called 'autofocus', it doesn't work.

Comment: Custom attributes are not valid in XHTML - what is your doctype? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413147/are-custom-attributes-ok-in-xhtml Autofocus is new in HTML5

Comment: I'm using the HTML5 doctype - <!DOCTYPE HTML>. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412947/do-html5-custom-data-attributes-work-in-ie-6. True, autofocus is not natively supported in IE<10, hence I'm trying to provide a shim. Please check the jsfiddle.

Comment: Have you tried something like this; $('[autofocus]:not(:focus)').eq(0).focus();

Answer (score 1):

I hit this same issue trying to autofocus after an AJAX call.

```
$("input[autofocus]").first().focus();
```

Just doesn't work.  I'm using IE 11.
I found if you remove the input selector it works. So....

```
$("[autofocus]").first().focus();
```